# How to query in Array with Typeorm's Repository

Tags: sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

This is the current repository code.
After joining the student and director tables in the attendance table, join the location table again in the student table, and join the schedule table in the director table to get the location information and date.

```
    return await this.createQueryBuilder('tbl_attendance')
      .leftJoin('tbl_attendance.student', 'student')
      .leftJoin('student.location', 'location')
      .select([
        'student.gcn',
        'student.id',
        'student.name',
        'tbl_attendance.period',
        'location.name',
        'tbl_attendance.state',
      ])
      .leftJoin('tbl_attendance.director', 'director')
      .leftJoin('director.schedule', 'schedule')
      .where('location.floor= :floor', { floor: floor })
      .andWhere('schedule.date= :date', { date: date })
      .andWhere('tbl_attendance.state= :state', { state: state })
      .getMany();
  }
```

And this is the currently returned json

```
[
    {
        "state": "MOVE",
        "period": 7,
        "student": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "anne",
            "gcn": "1301",
            "location": {
                "name": "semina 2-1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "state": "MOVE",
        "period": 8,
        "student": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "anne",
            "gcn": "1301",
            "location": {
                "name": "semina 2-1"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I wish it was returned like this.

```
[
        {
            "gcn": 1301,
            "student_id": 3,
            "student_name": "anne",
            "student_attendance": [
                 { 
                     "period" : 8
                     "location_name": null || "semina2-1",
                     "state": "MOVE"
            },
                {  
                    "period": 9
                     "location_name": null || "semina2-1",
                     "state": "MOVE"
            },
                { 
                     "period": 10
                     "location_name": null || "semina2-1",
                     "state":"MOVE"
            }
            ]
        }

]
```

How do I get the student's place id and status for each class separately as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should query the student table and join the related entities onto that one. That way, your result would be an array of students, with each its own array of attendance object.

Now, when it comes to joining with TypeORM, joined tables will always be nested in the resulting object, as an array or an object for one-to-many and many-to-one relationships respectively. There is no straightforward way to control the shape of the resulting data other than mapping it manually.